# Ordering multiple RestControllerAdvice properly in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-annotations

I create 2 exception handler classes as shown below:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler { ... }
```

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ValidationExceptionHandler { ... }
```

There is a handler method in `ValidationExceptionHandler` and as I want this handler catch the exception before catching in `DefaultExceptionHandler`, I set it `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`.

However, the annotation used in the other class (`@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`) gives warning like "redundant ..." for `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`. I know I can delete it, but I am wondering as the default handler class is lower precedence, could I just set `@Order()` or `@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` for the `DefaultExceptionHandler` without setting order for the `ValidationExceptionHandler`? Because setting last order means the others have priority. I tried but not working like that.

Should I have to set order for both of these handler classes? If so, how should I set order for the lower instead of `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` ?

Answer (score 1):

`Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` is the [default value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html#:%7E:text=Default%20is%20Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) for that annotation so you dont need to set it.

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: I only get a "Redundant default parameter value assignment" if i use `@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)`. However setting it to `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, correct. But I am wondering what if I just use `@Order()` for the lowest precedence handler and do not use order annotation for highest precedence handler?

Comment: Oh now I understand. Personally I would just set the one class to `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`

Comment: I also thought that. But if there are 4 classes, then you will add 3 annotation except from lower precedence class. But if I could just set lower precedence, then it would be better I think (just preventing general exception handler catch the exceptions before the specific ones)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Are you trying to catch the same Exception in all Classes?

Comment: No, but no need to do that. Because `DefaultExceptionHandler` could catch the exception if I do not set order properly.

Comment: Which exceptions are you handling in `DefaultExceptionHandler`?

Comment: Actually we do not need this info, because the problem is that: I want to set order for these 2 exception handling classes and I just want to set the order of default handler class to lower precedence and do not want to set the other's order. I am not sure if I have to set order of all of these classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246729/discussion-between-leguan-and-hans).

Comment: We cannot see our messages due to being busy. So, we may continue writing here

Comment: I dont think you need to set the Order then. You handle the exception only at one point.

Comment: But I treat the validation exceptions in a different manner